# Buffer to String with bytes as string

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, string, buffer

In Node.js I am getting a buffer result as:

`<Buffer 21 61 0b>`

How can I convert this to a string like this:

`“21610b”`

All the methods and suggestions I have seen online are for converting the buffer to a string but that will change the layout. I want to keep the exact same layout as string.

Comment: I am very confused as to why you would do this... this will completely change what the data is...

Comment: `.toString('hex')` maybe?

Comment: @about14sheep it sounds stupid but thats how I just need it :/

Comment: @Jonas Wilms that suggestion actually worked!! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The console summarizes Buffer objects by displaying the first few bytes in hexadecimal notation. To convert a Buffer to a string of hexadecimals, use `.toString('hex')`.